# Is there an example to demonstrate why $\frac{1}{(1/2)}$ equals $2$?

Tags: arithmetic, education, fractions

To explain why $\frac{1}{2}=\frac{2}{4}$ I use slices of pizza and show how eating one slice of a pizza cut in half is the same thing as eating two slices of a pizza cut in quarters.

Is there a way to show why $\frac{1}{(1/2)}=2$ using an example like the one above?

Comment: eating 2 halves of a pizza is same as eating one full pizza

Comment: @ganeshie8 That shows that $2 (1/2) = 1$. Ideally, I would like an example that shows the relationship directly.

Comment: Ahh I see, try this more direct one : how many slices of 1/2 size are there in a pizza ?

Answer (score 7):

If I eat one pizza in half an hour, that is the same rate as eating two pizzas per hour.

Answer (score 0):

I know you are looking for something about pizzas but I think fractions in general work better if you work with a definition more akin to the axiomatic definition.

I mean what is $\displaystyle\frac{1}{\pi}$ in terms of pizzas?

I would define $\displaystyle \frac{1}{x}$ as the number, which when multiplied by $x$, gives me 1. This works fine for pizzas because, e.g. $2\times\frac{1}{2}=1$ --- two half slices is the whole.

Now whatever $\displaystyle \frac{1}{\frac{1}{2}}$ is, if I multiply it by $\displaystyle \frac{1}{2}$ I get one so that

$$\frac{1}{\frac{1}{2}}\cdot\frac{1}{2} =1...$$

but this is nothing other than two... (or multiply both sides of the equation on the left by two).

Answer (score 0):

Use ratios.

Pizza will be consumed at a rate of one person per one-half pizza.

$$\frac{dP}{d\Pi} = \frac{1\ \textrm{person}}{\frac12\ \textrm{pizza}}.$$

Pizza is delivered at a rate of 1 pizza per day

$$\frac{d\Pi}{dt} = \frac{1\ \textrm{pizza}}{1\ \textrm{day}}.$$

To avoid an excess of pizza, we require at least

$$\frac{dP}{d\Pi}\frac{d\Pi}{dt} = \frac{1\ \textrm{person}}{\frac12\ \textrm{pizza}}\cdot \frac{1\ \textrm{pizza}}{1\ \textrm{day}} = 2 \frac{\textrm{person}}{\textrm{day}}.$$

Answer (score 0):

To get over compound fractions extend your first example to $=\frac{\frac12}1$ since it is the same serving as as eating $1/2$ of an entire pizza.

Looked at from the perspective of you feeding me:  $\frac42=\frac21$ because if you previously cut the pizza in $4$ slices and give me $2$ I have the same as if you cut it into $2$ slices and give me $1$ and both are the same as taking one entire pizza and giving me $1/2.$ Maybe candy bars are better.